# Alignment statistics

Tags: sequence-alignment

- Given a multi-fasta multiple sequence alignment file, is there a quick way/tool to calculate average pairwise sequence identity?
- Even better, given a whole genome alignment file (`.maf` or even `.hal`) is there a quick way/tool to calculate average pairwise sequence identity across the individual local multiple sequence alignments?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, and apologies for not accepting earlier. I found what I was looking for in [maftools](https://github.com/dentearl/mafTools/tree/master/mafCoverage), but agree the answer below was also useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of methods that do something similar to this. Is it necessary that it be *alignment* rather than a heuristic such as k-mer hashing?

If k-mer hashing is ok, then I would suggest [mash](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-016-0997-x) or [sourmash](https://sourmash.readthedocs.io/). There are additionally newer [fancy techniques](https://academic.oup.com/nargab/article/3/1/lqab001/6125549).

For just an old-school program that computes pairwise identities, [PHYLIP](https://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip.html) has programs DNADIST and PROTDIST that exactly compute identities. [Similar questions on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/301422/) suggest that PHYLIP's utilities are recommended even relatively recently elsewhere. But it looks like [Clustal Omega](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/clustalo/) also computes identities for free.

For microbial genomes a common statistic is [average nucleotide identity](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0580951714000087) (ANI), which may be what you are looking for. There are a variety of tools to do this, here is [one](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-07641-9), and [here is a webserver](http://enve-omics.ce.gatech.edu/ani/) that will do it for you.